SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx shrinks the console window by one line, why?
I was playing with Winapi and there's an odd behaviour happening when I call SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx, the console's window (not the buffer) shrinks by one line each time.
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX info = {sizeof(info)};

    if(!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(handle, &info)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error getting console info\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Update the console without doing any change.
    SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(handle, &info);

    printf("Hello, Console!\n");

    return 0;
}

This can be easily solved by doing info.srWindow.Bottom += 1 after each SetConsoleScreenInfo call.

There's nothing mentioned about it in the documentation.  It seems like an off-by-one bug.

This question is similar to: SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx ... bug?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Found an old duplicate that says it is a long-standing "won't fix" bug but no references.  It mentions incrementing both Right and Bottom, but only Bottom seems to be shrinking.

It seems an issue. I suggest you could post feedback via the Feedback button in the Doc.

Yes, same here.  I'm also incrementing much like you're doing.   I guess MS is not interested in fixing it?
